# An IDE does not respect environment variable in macOS

Tags: macos, environment-variables, zsh

Looks like I have messed up with my macOS settings because neither Xcode, nor CLion, nor QtCreator they can not see an env variable if I run the app from IDE.

If I run the app from the command line - the env vars are being respected as per they declared in ~/.zshenv.

How can I let macOS (10.15.6) propagate zsh env vars to any IDE I run?

Comment: Have a look here... https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/environment-variables-in-xcode-a78e07d223ed

Comment: Env vars set in ~/.zshenv only apply to zsh and programs run under zsh. GUI programs don't run under a shell at all (unless you do something weird that might cause other problems), so they inherently won't be available there. You need to find a different way to define them.

Comment: @drewpts : _I run the app from the command line_  .... How exactly do you do this? If the app is really a child process from your interactive shell, it inherits its environment.

Comment: @user1934428 , yup it was a child. Actually, the comments above shed a light on a gap in my understanding: the macOS UI shell does not inherit a zsh variables... I thought if I run an app from IDE started from UI , a variable will be propagated from zsh -> UI -> IDE -> a binary. But it is not. :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with zsh. The process of inheriting the environment is built into the operating system. How did you prove that the app was really a child process of your zsh? You didn't even show in your question the code which started the app.

Comment: Environment variables propagate from parent process to child process; that's it. A GUI app typically has `launchd` as its parent process, and you can (for example) use `launchctl` to ask `launchd` to add a value to its environment for a child to inherit.

Comment: macOS is fundamentally different from, say, Linux, where the login manager and your GUI are themselves children of some shell process.